# Is an h-inductive sentence equivalent to a universal-existential sentence?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

I am studying Positive Model Theory and from this context, I bumped into this question. It should make sense, considering the Chang-Los-Suszko theorem. However I fail to rewrite it in that way.

So, a h-inductive sentence is a finite conjunction of sentences of the form $$\forall\bar x(\exists\bar y\phi(\bar x,\bar y)\rightarrow\exists\bar z\psi(\bar x,\bar z)),$$ where $\phi$ and $\psi$ are quantifier free.

I suppose that if I can show this form arises in a conjunction of two such sentences, I am done. So, consider $$(\forall\bar x_1(\exists\bar y_1\phi(\bar x_1,\bar y_1)\rightarrow\exists\bar z_1\psi(\bar x_1,\bar z_1)))\wedge(\forall\bar x_2(\exists\bar y_2\phi(\bar x_2,\bar y_2)\rightarrow\exists\bar z_2\psi(\bar x_2,\bar z_2))).$$

Is it possible to rewrite this as $\forall\bar p\exists\bar qf(\bar p,\bar q)$, where $f$ is quantifier free?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Quite generally, the conjunction of two $\forall\exists$ sentences is equivalent to another $\forall\exists$ sentence. Specifically, $(\forall x\exists y\,\alpha)\land(\forall u\exists v\,\beta)$ is equivalent to $\forall x\forall u\exists y\exists v\,(\alpha\land\beta)$.

Comment: I see, since the two conjuncted sentences are $\forall\exists$ sentences (which I have already worked out off-screen), their conjunction has to be one too, according to what you say. Then, I have a follow up question: what "rules" do you use to derive your statement?

Comment: I didn't use "rules" but just observed that the equivalence is semantically valid. Note that it's one instance of the standard procedure for converting formulas to prenex normal form. Most textbooks on first-order logic should give that procedure and indicate how it's justified by whatever rules that textbook has chosen for its deductive system.